# PyQT5: can't get the path variable to work outside it's function

Tags: python, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I'm trying to save in a variable **source_folder** a selected path.
Although if I print the variable in the function it works, but it be used outside the function.

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QFileDialog
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 800, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Filer Sorter v.1.0")

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("""
            Usage:
                - Select the source folder
                            """)
        self.label.adjustSize()
        self.label.move(-10, - 10)

        self.source_folder = None

        self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button_1.setText("Source Folder")
        self.button_1.move(10, 80)
        self.button_1.clicked.connect(self.open_dialog_box)
        print(self.source_folder) # doesn't work


    def open_dialog_box(self):
        self.source_folder = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self,
            'Select the source Folder:',
            'C:\\',
            QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
        print(self.source_folder) # here it works

def window():
    app =QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

Thanks a bunch you guys.

Comment: You're calling `self.initUI()` in the constructor method, so it cannot possibly save that variable until `open_dialog_box` gets called after clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

`InitUI()` will execute only when class object created. so after button press `print` instruction of `InitUI()` won't work. This is not the issue of the scope of that var at all.

you can test this by adding a new function and calling it from `open_dialog_box`

```
def printSourceFolder(self):
    print(self.source_folder)

def open_dialog_box(self):
        self.source_folder = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self,
            'Select the source Folder:',
            'C:\\',
            QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
        print(self.source_folder) # here it works
        self.printSourceFolder()
```